# Триггеры. Реагирование не на свое событие

Tags: wpf, xaml

Можно ли через триггеры изменить один объект после возникновения какого-либо события в другом?
К примеру, изменить цвет одного прямоугольника если курсор будет над другим прямоугольником.

Самому себе мы меняем заливку так, а как воздействовать не на себя?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:key="changeFill" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}"
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>    

<StackPanel>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect1" Width="20" Height="20"
               Style="{StaticResource changeFill}">
     <Rectangle x:Name="rect2" Width="20" Height="20">
 </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Если стиль внутри контрола, можно использовать TargetName, кажется.

Comment: @VladD это должен быть ответ, а не комментарий, кажется ;)

Comment: @FoggyFinder: Ну, к примеру из вопроса это не подходит, поэтому наверное всё же не ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения - использовать `DataTrigger` :

```
    <Style x:Key="changeFill" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=rect2, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="Green"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=rect2, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Rectangle.Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Как написал в комментариях [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) вы можете использовать свойство `TargetName` если имя находится в области видимости стиля.